# Retrieve data inside nested array in MongoDB and paginate aggregation show all docs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If there are following documents inside a collection:

```
{
    "_id": "8048d05478813e439442abac",
    "projectName": "Y-10000-A",
    "archived": false,
    "tabs":
        [
            {
                "visible": true,
                "permisos": ["604892e9266fc72b04be62f0", "12312131b04be62f0"]
            },
            {
                "visible": true,
                "permisos": ["12312131b04be62f0"]
            }
        ],
},
{
    "_id": "9048d05478813e439442abad",
    "projectName": "Y-10000-B",
    "archived": false,
    "tabs": [{
        "visible": true,
        "permisos": ["12312131b04be62f0"]
    }]
},
{
    "_id": "9048d05478813e439442abae",
    "projectName": "Y-10000-C",
    "archived": true,
    "tabs": [{
        "visible": true,
        "permisos": ["604892e9266fc72b04be62f0"]
    }]
},
```

I want to filter all the projects that have at least one `tab` matching the `user._id` in the `permisos` array. Also I am filtering by archived and by text. The text search isn't working properly.

```
const projectsAggregation = await projectSchema.aggregate([
     { $match: { $text: { $search: "Y" } } },
      { $match : { archived: false} },
       {
            $addFields: {
              
                tabs: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$tabs",
                        as: "tab",
                        cond: { $in: [user._id, "$$tab.permisos"] }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
          $match: {
              $expr: {
                  $gt: [{ $size: "$tabs" }, 0]
              }
          }
      }


const projectsDocs = await projectSchema.aggregatePaginate(projectsAggregation, {
      limit: pagination.limit ? parseInt(pagination.limit) : 10,
      page: pagination.page ? parseInt(pagination.page) + 1 : 1
    });
```

I want to paginate the aggregation. I am using mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2. It returns all the documents of the schema. It should return only the documents from projectsAggregation. Also the
`{ $match: { $text: { $search: "Y" } } }`, it doesn't work.

Comment: The way you are passing `projectsAggregation` to `projectSchema.aggregatePaginate` is wrong. That is why u are getting all the documents. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Raw query:

```js
let user_id = "604892e9266fc72b04be62f0";
let regex = /^Y/

db.projects.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: {
            archived: false,
            projectName: {
                $regex: regex,
                $options: 'i'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            tabs: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$tabs",
                    as: "tab",
                    cond: { $in: [user_id, "$$tab.permisos"] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gt: [{ $size: "$tabs" }, 0]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Using Mongoose:

File: project_schema.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2');


let projectSchema = new Schema({
// Put your schema here
}, 
{
  collection: 'projects'
});

projectSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);        // <- This step is important!

module.exports = mongoose.model('projects', projectSchema);
```

File: project_manager.js

```
let user_id = "604892e9266fc72b04be62f0";
let regex = /^Y/

const projectAggQuery = projectSchema.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      archived: false,
      projectName: {
        $regex: regex,
        $options: 'i'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      tabs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$tabs",
          as: "tab",
          cond: { $in: [user_id, "$$tab.permisos"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [{ $size: "$tabs" }, 0]
      }
    }
  }
]);

const projectsDocs = await projectSchema.aggregatePaginate(projectAggQuery, {
  limit: pagination.limit ? parseInt(pagination.limit) : 10,
  page: pagination.page ? parseInt(pagination.page) + 1 : 1
});
```

Comment: Good! Thanks! If i want to add a new condition for projectName? I create a new agregation inside?

Comment: ````db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {{ $match : { projectName: "Y-10000-C" } }},{
        $addFields: {
            tabs: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$tabs",
                    as: "tab",
                    cond: { $in: [user_id, "$$tab.permisos"] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gt: [{ $size: "$tabs" }, 0]
            }
        }
    }
]);````

Comment: like this? .aggregate[{$amtch},{addFields},{$match}]

Comment: I have tried and then it doesn't work for the addFields, it doesnt return correctly. Also I have do it const projectsDocs = await projectSchema.aggregatePaginate(projectsAggregation, {
      limit: pagination.limit ? parseInt(pagination.limit) : 10,
      page: pagination.page ? parseInt(pagination.page) + 1 : 1
    }); AND returns ALL the projects, not only the projectsAggregation. I edit the question

Comment: I have edited the question. Yes I am using it.

Comment: The way you are passing `projectsAggregation` to `projectSchema.aggregatePaginate` is wrong. Check the updated answer.